# Hibernate - TypedQuery.getResultList() returns a list of the same object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

Here is a more and maybe better description of the problem:

I do a simple select query. The returning list contains the exact number of records/objects as if I do the same query in the DB, but  the problem is that all the objects are the same/identical.

For ex, this is the result in the DB (I removed the null values):
26801  01-JAN-00  7  31-DEC-99  7     Obere Kirchstr. 26  CH 8304  Walliselln
26801  01-JAN-00  2  31-DEC-99  2  Obere Kirchstr. 26  CH  8304  Walliselln

And this is the content of the variable addresses as I can see it in Eclipse during the debugging after the query has been executed:

addresses   ArrayList  (id=81)
  elementData   Object[10]  (id=86)
    [0] DLDBAddress  (id=82)
    [1] DLDBAddress  (id=82)
    [2] null
    ...
  modCount  1
  size  2

DLDBAddress [persid=26801, valPeriodStart=1900-01-01, valPeriodEnd=9999-12-31, addressNr=7, addressType=7, addressRow1=null, addressRow2=Obere Kirchstr. 26, addressRow3=null, country=CH , postalCode=8304, city=Walliselln, phoneNr=null, faxNr=null, sekretaryPhoneNr=null, alternatPhoneNr=null, pagerNr=null]

DLDBAddress [persid=26801, valPeriodStart=1900-01-01, valPeriodEnd=9999-12-31, addressNr=7, addressType=7, addressRow1=null, addressRow2=Obere Kirchstr. 26, addressRow3=null, country=CH , postalCode=8304, city=Walliselln, phoneNr=null, faxNr=null, sekretaryPhoneNr=null, alternatPhoneNr=null, pagerNr=null]]

As you can see, the two objects are identical. They shoul instead differ from the addressNr and addressType...

This is the piece of code where I build up the query:

```
public static <T> List<T> findBy(EntityManager eM, Class<T> boClass, String whereClause, String whereValue)  
 {
    EntityManager entityManager = eM;
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from " + boClass.getName() + " s where s." + whereClause + " = " + whereValue);
    ...
    return (List<T>) query.getResultList();
}
```

and this is the (quite simple) resulting query:

from ch.ethz.id.wai.pdb.bo.DLDBAddress s where s.persid = 26801

This is the generated query:

```
Hibernate: 
select
dldbaddres0_.PERSID as PERSID0_,
dldbaddres0_.ADRNUM as ADRNUM0_,
dldbaddres0_.ADRZEIL1 as ADRZEIL3_0_,
dldbaddres0_.ADRZEIL2 as ADRZEIL4_0_,
dldbaddres0_.ADRZEIL3 as ADRZEIL5_0_,
dldbaddres0_.ADRTYP as ADRTYP0_,
dldbaddres0_.ADRAUSWTEL as ADRAUSWTEL0_,
dldbaddres0_.ADRORT as ADRORT0_,
dldbaddres0_.ADRLAND as ADRLAND0_,
dldbaddres0_.ADRFAX as ADRFAX0_,
dldbaddres0_.ADRPSA as ADRPSA0_,
dldbaddres0_.ADRTEL as ADRTEL0_,
dldbaddres0_.ADRPLZ as ADRPLZ0_,
dldbaddres0_.ADRSEKTEL as ADRSEKTEL0_,
dldbaddres0_.BISDAT as BISDAT0_,
dldbaddres0_.VONDAT as VONDAT0_ 
from
NETHZ.V_DLDB_ADRESSE dldbaddres0_ 
where
dldbaddres0_.PERSID=26801
```

And here the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "V_DLDB_ADRESSE", schema="NETHZ")
public class DLDBAddress
{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "PERSID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Integer   persid;
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  @Column(name = "VONDAT", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Date   valPeriodStart;
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  @Column(name = "BISDAT", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Date   valPeriodEnd;
  @Column(name = "ADRNUM", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Integer addressNr;
  @Column(name = "ADRTYP", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Integer addressType;
  @Column(name = "ADRZEIL1", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String addressRow1;
  @Column(name = "ADRZEIL2", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String addressRow2;
  @Column(name = "ADRZEIL3", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String addressRow3;
  @Column(name = "ADRLAND", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String country;
  @Column(name = "ADRPLZ", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String postalCode;
  @Column(name = "ADRORT", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String city;
  @Column(name = "ADRTEL", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String phoneNr;
  @Column(name = "ADRFAX", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String faxNr;
  @Column(name = "ADRSEKTEL", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String secretaryPhoneNr;
  @Column(name = "ADRAUSWTEL", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String alternatPhoneNr;
  @Column(name = "ADRPSA", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String pagerNr;

...
```

Am I missing something?

Ah, I'm connecting to an Oracle DB.

Thanks in advance
Francesco

Comment: 1. I'd be more likely to use hql than CriteriaBuilder as the queries are easier to read. 2. Without seeing the where clause passed to the method, it'd be hard to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: In my experience, using JPA & Hibernate EntityManager, this happens when the id is not really unique, which is mandatory in JPA. Hibernate EntityManager fully implements JPA 2 so that should apply here as well. Would you post your entities as well?

Comment: What is the actual SQL being generated by Hibernate?  Change your Hibernate configuration to show that information.  That might provide a better explanation as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Erik you were right. In my class I set persid as @Id, but it' not unique. I defined a composite ID and now it works!  Thank you very much.

Comment: Uh. Posted answer not noticed that you mentioned in the comment that the problem is solved. Anyway, my answer may help to explain Hib's behaviour.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
where dldbaddres0_.PERSID=26801

@Id
  @Column(name = "PERSID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

You defined PERSID as @Id, which is a primary key. Is it really unique for your application? From the behavior it is not. But for Hib it MUST be.

So what happens:

1. You have two+ records in the database with PERSID = 26801
2. You query them WHERE PERSID=26801
3. SQL Query returns two+ rows
4. Hib loads first one, and puts into session, with PERSID as a key (because it is marked as @Id). Object is placed into the result list.
5. Hib loads second one, notices that an object with same @Id is already in the session, and just places the reference into the result List. Row data are ignored.
6. Thus you get two+ copies.