# JPA Returning Same Data for 2 different rows in Database

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

There are two Entities: `Employee.java` and `Company.java`, with a  bidirectional `@ManyToOne` relationship; Employee has `@ManyToOne` Relationhip with Company, and Company has `@OnetoMany` relationship with Employee.

When I am firing a named query.
`Select c from Company c where c.Id='100';` 2 records are returned for employee but both rows have the same data, where as if I check in the Database, I can see there are two different employee rows for the column which is joining both tables.

Can anybody give a pointer on whcih direction I should think and try to resolve ?

Comment: Can you post the two rows as they are in your DB identifying which one was returned (twice).?

Comment: You are querying for Company but two employees are returned? I think you have to rewrite your question and show some code...

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding from your writing above your database query returning the same result set. To solve this kind of problem we are using candidate key. In your program if you add one more column **count** to company table then we can use both employee_id and count as a candidate key. Plz update your code so i can modified it as per you need.

Alternatively you can add a auto increment id in your company table then also it will work

Comment: The Entity Relationship is bidirectional ,Customer <----1:M---->Vehicle ..The Vehicle Table have primary key as CustomerId which is the primary key of Customer.. those Vehicles have same Primary key as  customerId..When i fetch that Customer with JPQL Query:.If there are two vehicles associated with that customer "BMW" and "AUDI"...I am getting "BMW" two times since the Primary key of both Vehicles are same..Same sort of problem here(Not Detailed Solution):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352357/hibernate-typedquery-getresultlist-returns-a-list-of-the-same-object...